# How to add WebSphere Application Server 9 to Rational Application Developer 9.5?

Tags: websphere, application-server

How do I add WebSphere Application Server 9 to Rational Application Developer 9.5? It's not showing up in the existing servers list.

When I open the IBM Installation Manager > Modify > RAD, there is no WAS 9 support feature to add.

I have been updating my environment non-stop, it's fully patched.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
Bert

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

As of yet (2016-07), WAS 9.0 is not supported by Rational Application Developer 9.5.

Instead, download and install Eclipse Neon, then install in it the "WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse Neon" from:
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Neon

Procedure:

Unzip the latter to folder "WAS9plugin" (my file was called libertytools-update-site_16.0.0.2.v20160602_2252.zip) and in Eclipse Neon do menu > Install New Software > Add > Local > browse and select folder "WAS9plugin" > OK button > in the Available software dialog check the item that appears called "WebSphere Application Server Liberty Tools for Eclipse 16.0.0.2" > click Finish.

Once installed and Eclipse has rebooted, menu Help > Install WebSphere Software > scroll to the bottom of the list > select to Install "WebSphere Application Server V9.0 Tools" > Finish button.

You will then be able to add the Servers view to the Eclipse workbench, then right-click Servers > select New > WebSphere Application Server 9.0